# Differentiation of an integral using fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

y = $\int_{0}^{x^2}  cos (u^ {\frac {1}{3}}) du    $

Find $\frac {dy}{dx}$

My answer

y = $3\sin(x^\frac 23)$

$\frac {dy}{dx} = 2cos(x^{\frac23})(x^{\frac{-1}3})$

But by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the answer should be $y = 2xcos(x^{\frac23})$ right?

Comment: The answer $y = 2xcos(x^{\frac23})$ is O.K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your antiderivative is wrong i think it must be
$3\,{\frac {\sin \left( {x}^{2/3} \right) {x}^{5/3}-2\,\sin \left( {x}^
{2/3} \right) \sqrt [3]{x}+2\,\cos \left( {x}^{2/3} \right) x}{\sqrt [
3]{x}}}
$

Comment: ahh havent touched integration for so long that I messed up my antiderivative..... Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You don't need integration. Just apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: but there was still an answer, not the way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

note that the integrand is not a function of $x$. look at the more general case:
$$
y = \int_0^{f(x)} \phi(u) du = \Phi(f(x)) - \Phi(0)
$$
where $\Phi$ is an antiderivative of the integrand $\phi$

differentiating:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} =\Phi'(f(x)) f'(x)
$$
("function of a function")

but by definition $\Phi' = \phi$ and here $f'(x)=2x$ hence
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x \cos (x^2)^{\frac13} = 2x \cos x^{\frac23}
$$
as you observed