# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus With Weird Limits

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

$$f(x) =\int_6^{x^3} \sin^3(5t) \, dt$$
what is $f'(x)$?

I know I have to use fundamental theorem of calculus, but what do I do about the $x^3$ and $t^3$?

Comment: use the FTC and the chain rule (for the $x^3$ part)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Firstly, please use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), since it will increase readability. Secondly, it is here mandatory to show some effort or give some thoughts about the problem. Thirdly, there are already tons of questions like this, for example [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969812/differentiation-of-an-integral-using-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus). Try to search: "differentiating using fundamental theorem of calculus".

Comment: The $t^3$ term is easy as it appears nowhere.

Comment: Use the chain rule.  (See the details in my answer below.) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

**The fundamental theorem of calculus:**

if $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ then $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

We have $F(x)=\int_{6}^{x^3}\sin ^3 (5t)dt$.

Let $\alpha = x^3$. then $F(\alpha ^ {\frac{1}{3}})=\int_{6}^{\alpha}\sin ^3 (5t)dt$

Now derive: $(F(\alpha ^ {\frac{1}{3}}) )'=\frac{1}{3}\alpha ^ {\frac{-2}{3}}F'(\alpha ^{\frac{1}{3}}) $

That was from chain rule. But we also know from FTC that it is equal to $\sin ^3(5 \alpha)$.

So you have $\frac{1}{3}\alpha ^ {\frac{-2}{3}}F'(\alpha ^{\frac{1}{3}}) =\sin ^3(5 \alpha)$. Solve for $F'(\alpha ^ {\frac{1}{3}})$ and return to $x$ rather than $\alpha$.

Also, next time do try to show more effort or indication that you tried something.

Welcome to Math SE.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the chain rule:**
\begin{align}
y & = \int_6^{x^3} \sin^3(5t)\,dt \\[12pt]
y & = \int_6^u \sin^3(5t)\,dt \\[6pt]
u & = x^3 \\[10pt]
\text{Therefore } \frac{dy}{du} & = \sin^3(5u) \\[6pt]
\text{and } \frac{du}{dx} & = 3x^2 \\[10pt]
\text{so } & \underbrace{\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}}_\text{chain rule} = \sin^3(5u)\cdot 3x^2 \\[15pt]
& = \sin^3(5x^3)\cdot 3x^2.
\end{align}